# Traverse though array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, traversal

I would like to know if this is a suitable way to traverse through an array in c++.

```
     int array[] = {4,3,2};

     int n = 0;

    // traverse through array

    while (array[n] >=0){

    cout << array[n];
    n++;

   }
```

It works for me in my current problem to sort integer arrays.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would even think this would work in the first place. What's the logic behind it?

Comment: I assumed that if the next elemnt array is -ve it means its a garbage value. But I realize now that its not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the data after your array is less than zero. In the typical case you cannot assume this, and so while this loop may work for now, eventually it will break. What you should be doing is looping from zero until you reach the length of the array instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cout << array[i];
```

or, you can use the new range-for loop in C++11:

```
for (int i : array)
    cout << i;
```

Long story short: no. Your loop will not work 100% of the time, and therefore you should not use it.

Comment: Good, but to be more C++11, one can use `auto`. Also since we are just printing the element, we can just use a `const` reference, no need to copy the element. For example, `for( auto const & i : array )`

Comment: You are correct. However they're ints. A const reference will add negligible speed improvements.

Comment: @bstamour In general, a const reference to an `int` will be slower than just copying it (although in most cases, the compiler will optimize both into the same code).

Comment: That's assuming the compiler implements references as pointers. They aren't required to use storage. In general, you should just measure it.

Answer (score 3):

Why on earth do you thing that would work?  Most of the time, it
won't.  If your array contains `0`, it obviously won't, and if
your array doesn't contain `0`, it's very likely to continue too
far (resulting in undefined behavior).

To traverse the array:

```
for ( int n: array ) {
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

Or in pre-C++11:

```
for ( int* current = begin( array ); current != end( array); ++ current ) {
    std::cout << *current << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11, you can also do this, and you don't even have to
write your own versions of `begin` and `end`.  Pre C++11, you'll
need:

```
template <typename T, size_t n>
T* 
begin( T (&array)[n] )
{
    return array;
}

template <typename T, size_t n>
T*
end( T (&array)[n] )
{
    return array + n;
}
```

Put them in some universally included header.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen an `end` definition like that. Where does the compiler get the information about `n` from, though? Surely this won't work for dynamically allocated arrays?

Comment: @JSQuareD It's so universal that it was adopted into C++11.  As for dynamically allocated arrays, `std::vector<>` has `begin` and `end` functions (and it's not rare, and C++11 does it, to overload `begin` and `end` so that they use the member functions on a container).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int array[] = {4,3,2};

    // number of elements in array
    int const n = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[ 0 ] );

    // traverse through array and print each element
    for( int i = 0; i != n; ++i ) {
         cout << array[ i ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are assuming that the index that doesn't have a value assigned by you will contain a `-ve` number, which isn't true.

You should always traverse using the size of the array:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++) //here size is the size of the array
{
// operation on array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[] = {4,3,2};

for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << array[i] << '\n';
}
```

Or in `C++11`

```
for (int x : array)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```